# Disable Ctrl-Z in normal mode

Tags: gvim

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> in normal mode, it makes my gVim "minimized" or in vim (not gVim ) it goes back to the shell.

I want to disable this feature but

- I can't unmap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>: `unmap <c-z>` returns `no such mapping`
- There is no option called `suspend`, allowing me to use `unset suspend`.

I did `:help suspend` but the document doesn't mention anything about disabling "suspend".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So there are several things that you need to understand:

Firstly you can't use `:unset suspend` and that is normal. Suspending Vim is not controlled by an option (that you could unset) but by a command: `:suspend`. See [`:h :suspend`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:suspend)

Secondly you want to disable the suspension triggered by <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>. This is a built-in command, thus you can not "unmap" this key combination. The only mappings that you can unmap are the one that you (or a plugin) created with a command `:map <key> <action>`.

What you can do is to say to Vim "When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> do nothing instead of suspending as you usually do".

This is what this command does:

```
nnoremap <c-z> <nop>
```

You can understand it like this:

```
n                      Do the following mapping only in normal mode
 nore                  Don't make it recursive (This is not necessary here but strongly recommended in all your mappings)
     map               Create a mapping
         <c-z>         The keys that you want to remap
               <nop>   This is the short for "no operation" i.e. Do nothing
```

You can add the line to your vimrc or simply type in vim's command line `:nnoremap <c-z> <nop>` so that the mapping will only exists in the current session.

See [`:h <nop>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#<nop>).

Comment: I was using neovim on windows with cmder, habit of ctrl+z'ing made neovim suspend itself but since there is no job control, I wasn't able to get back into neovim. Hence every time this is triggered I had to kill the process. Unmapping suspend did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

You can map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> to anything you want in gVim. You do not need to first unmap it.

In fact, `mswin.vim`, which comes with the gVim package, already maps it to undo like this:
`noremap <C-Z> u`